# ASP Classic - Error When include connect file

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I have two files in the same folder like:

```
Example
|-connect.asp
|-default.asp
```

connect.asp contains:

```vbs
   <%
    'declare the variables 
    Dim Connection
    Dim ConnString

    'define the connection string, specify database driver
    ConnString="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myServername;UID=myUsername;" & _ 
               "PWD=myPassword;DATABASE=myDatabasename"

    'create an instance of the ADO connection and recordset objects
    Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    'Open the connection to the database
    Connection.Open ConnString
 %>
```

and default.asp contains:

```
<!-- #include virtual="connect.asp" -->
<% 
Dim Recordset
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
%>
```

But when I run localhost/example i get an error:

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please
>   contact the system administrator. If you are the system administrator
>   please click here to find out more about this error.

If I do not use the include file, and write it all in one file, then it works.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: If you have access to your server this page might help you get more useful error messages http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: You should turn off friendly error messages in IE and make sure the server is sending detailed error messages so we can get a more meaningful error message. Alternately, write some error trapping code and record the detailed error message somewhere - either way knowing the specific error will help get more meaningful answers.

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

```
<!--#include file="connect.asp" -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with an older app. I had to provide the absolute path of the script.

It the script is at the top level

Or if it's in another folder such as "includes"

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what I addressed in the comment, the format of your include statement is off.

If you're going to do a virtual include, it should look like this:

```vbs
<!-- #include virtual="/connect.asp" -->
<% 
Dim Recordset
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
%>
```

If you're going to do a file include, it should look like this:

```vbs
<!-- #include file="connect.asp" -->
<% 
Dim Recordset
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
%>
```

Virtual includes start at the root of the virtual directory (`/`) and go from there. File includes use a relative path from the page including the file.